# Regex validation for phone numbers not behaving as expected

Tags: validation

I have a regex expression that validates a set of mobile numbers:
The numbers have optional prefixes (+234 or 234 or 0) and I have used the alternation with the pipe character. Immediately following the international code or zero character is a set of service provider specific identifiers that I have also specified the options using the alternation character.

Based on the regex I have, this number should not be valid (12349098766543); but the regex returns it as valid. It appears the there is a match on `909` in the code. But shouldn't the presence of `1` at the beginning of the test string enforce a validation failure?
What is wrong with the regex i have here?

Thanks

```
function check_number($number) {
if(!preg_match('/[+234|234|0]?(704|702|803|806|703|706|813|816|810|814|903|802|708|808|812|701|902|809|817|818|909|908|805|705|815|807|811|905)\d{7}$/', $number)) {
    return 'Invalid Phone Number';
}else{
    return 'valid Phone Number';}
```

}

The execution below should fail, but is is passed as valid.

```
$str = '12349098766543';
echo check_number($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer elsewhere, so I am posting it here in case anyone comes across this same issue:

[+234|234|0] makes no sense. The square brackets denote a list of characters, but i want alternatives: (?:\+?234|0). Read: Either an optional plus sign followed by 234, or the digit 0.

The + character is a meta character in regular expressions and must be escaped.

Use the \A and \z anchors to match the beginning and end of the input.

```
/\\A(?:\\+?234|0)?(?:704|702|803|806|703|706|813|816|810|814|903|802|708|808|812|701|902|809|817|818|909|908|805|705|815|807|811|905)\\d{7}\\z/
```